# Django endless pagination 2 settings

Tags: django

I'm been using the plugin called django endless pagination and it's been working well . The main settings for the pagination are specify in the settings.py . What happen if you want to specify another pagination settings such as 3 pagination per page for another template?

This is the first settings but what if I wanted to specify for another template , 3 pagination per page?

How could this be done ?

```
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE = 2
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PREVIOUS_LABEL = 'Previous'
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_NEXT_LABEL = 'Next'



ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE = 3
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PREVIOUS_LABEL = 'Previous'
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_NEXT_LABEL = 'Next'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the `settings.py` module for the `django-endless-pagination`](https://github.com/frankban/django-endless-pagination/blob/master/endless_pagination/settings.py#L8), you'll see that it specifically mentions that you can override the value in the templatetag:

```
# How many objects are normally displayed in a page
# (overwriteable by templatetag).
PER_PAGE = getattr(settings, 'ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE', 10)
```

Looking at [the documentation for the template tag](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags_reference.html#paginate), it's easy to specify how many objects you want to display:

```
{% paginate 20 entries %}
```